# striped bi-colour bar graph using MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

How can I draw a chart as shown using MS Excel 2016? My sample data is

[image: Sample Data]

[image: Example curve]

I have tried conditional formatting using MOD(ROW(),2) to highlight even and odd rows then print them in overlapping manner, but things turned messy. There will be two striped bars, one for each column.

Comment: A bit confused... how does conditional formatting relate to a chart? They're two separate things entirely.

Comment: My excel knowledge is very poor. Just trying what ever I was getting from google 

Comment: Just need to draw a graph like that

Answer (score 0):

Found at last. I need to select each column and from the format option, colour icon , substitute the solid colour with textured colour by selecting the base colour and texture type. Repeat for every column. Never explored beyond the default values in excel so far. Still need to learn a lot.